# Identical ID's in the same HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tags

I have a page that has two different inputs that contain same ID but each one in different form. and I'm actually setting values to inputs from javascript using get element by ID. I know this is not valid. but the  thing is if i change one of the input id's I'm gonna need to re write a bunch of code in 'shopping cart ' cuz these input's pass value to cart. I'm actually not planning to touch that for now. So, is there any trick that can target one input instead of the other even  if they have the same id's??

ex:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cart_1_ID_Add2"  id="cart_1_ID_Add2" value=""/>


<input type="hidden" name=cart_1_ID_Add2"   id="cart_1_ID_Add2" value=""/>
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well, you'd have to use something other than `getElementById()`, since you're requiring that the IDs not be useful.  `document.querySelector()` may work, if you can devise a query which identifies the target element.

Comment: You need to change one of those form IDs. You cant have the same ID used more than once on a page - and getElementById() will certainly never work so long as you do.

Comment: An ID **should be unique** within a page (the same way people have unique IDs within a "nation")

Comment: the thing is that these inputs are not getting any value assined to them from javascript other than get element by id & name together so basically I have to assign same name and id to input in order for it to get datafrom javascript.

Comment: You can use `name` or `class` if you want to identify an element by something else. That as others have pointed out is not the standard way of doing it. If you go back and change it right now to have unique Ids you might be spared having to back later on and having it even worse.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is a wrong practice, and you should use different id's, you could add a different class attribute to each one.

```
<input class="input1" type="hidden" name="cart_1_ID_Add2"  id="cart_1_ID_Add2" value=""/>
<input class="input2" type="hidden" name=cart_1_ID_Add2"   id="cart_1_ID_Add2" value=""/>

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("input1")[0];
```

Again: I strongly recommend you to find time to change the logic of your program to use unique id's.

Comment: This is a very good idea to be fair. However, I think it's important to state that ID and class should be switched in a normal use case - using classes as IDs shouldn't be considered the norm.

Comment: Actually I totally agree @mfisher91. The right way would be using unique id's and repeated classes (if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

If they are in different forms you can target them by selecting IDs where they are inside a certain class. You can also change the `name` attribute and select that instead.

HTML

```
<div class="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="rename1"   id="cart_1_ID_Add2" value="">
</div>
<div class="form2">
    <input type="hidden" name="rename2"   id="cart_1_ID_Add2" value="">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".form1 #cart_1_id_add2")
//Or
$("input[name*='rename1']")
```

However you shouldn't really have the same id twice on one page otherwise it makes it hard to maintain and debug.  If it's not a huge job to change your approach I'd recommend you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Add another attribute to one or both tags.
For example, you can make them

```
<input type="hidden"name="cart_1_ID_Add2"  id="cart_1_ID_Add2" data-id="add100"  class="myInput" value=""/>


<input type="hidden" name=cart_1_ID_Add2"   id="cart_1_ID_Add2" data-id="add101" class="myInput" value=""/>
```

Then get their values with jQuery

```
var myInput = $('[data-id=add100]').val();

console.log(myInput);
```

OR use plain javascript by adding a class and getting the value

```
 var myVal = document.getElementsByClassName("myInput")[0];
 console.log(myVal.value);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
That code shouldn't have duplicate id properties in Dom btw.

You can use a custom HTML element property:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cart_1_ID_Add2"  id="cart_1_ID_Add2" value="" my-property="some_identifier"/>


<input type="hidden" name=cart_1_ID_Add2"   id="cart_1_ID_Add2" value="" my-property="some_identifier2"/>
```